# Chrome : Text blurry when skew back : skew(-10deg) -> skew(10deg)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms, skew

I just want to skew the parent and **skew it back** on the child.

**Example : HTML**

```
<div class="parent"> <!-- skew(-10deg) -->
    <div class="child">Hello</div> <!-- skew(10deg) (skew back) -->
</div>
```

**Example : CSS**

```
.parent {
    transform: skew(-10deg);
}
.child {
    transform: skew(10deg);
}
```

Text inside seems ok with Firefox, Safari. But not **Chrome** and **Opera** its a bit blurry

*I have to use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` for reduce box pixelated in Chrome*

**Firefox :**

[image: Firefox]

**Chrome :**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox vs Chrome :**

[image: FirefoxVSChrome]

**or zoomed by Photoshop**

[image: FirefoxVSChromeZoomed]

**Live example :** http://jsfiddle.net/1tpj1kka/

Any idea ?

---

**NOTE !!! : web-tiki's answer is an another way solution to prevent the problem. But if any answered a real solution to resolved this skew back problem (real fix), I will accept the answer.**

Comment: Why don't you use a `pseudo-element` for that? It has better browser support , rather then `transform`.

Comment: @Vucko Does not matter ? http://jsfiddle.net/uy061t79/2/

Comment: @l2aelba [I ment like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/uy061t79/3/)

Comment: @Vucko Thanks, But I have to do like I coded in my case.

Comment: Visually nice question. How did you create the animated gif?

Comment: Thanks, Just a online gif maker @redochka

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "blurry text" after 2d or 3d transforms with webkit browsers has been [discused many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=blurry%20text%20transform%20%5Bcss%5D%20is%3Aquestion). But in your case, you can apply the transform only on a pseudo element so that your text isn't affected by the skew property.

It will also alow you to use only one tag in your markup :

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
body{color:#fff;font-weight: bold;font-size:50px;font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif;}

.parent {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5%;
    position:relative;
}

.parent::before {
    content :'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background: rgba(90,190,230,0.9);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    transform:skew(-10deg);
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Hello
</div>
```

Comment: +up. Good idea. Thanks

Comment: My scenario was a bit different (I needed to fix a blurry image within a div that is skewed) but this tip helped me. +1 up

Answer (score 2):

Adding the 'translateZ(0)' before transformations like below forces the gpu to re-render the text and removes blurry-ness on Chrome.

This:

```
transform:  translateZ(0) skew(-10deg);
```

Not This:

```
transform: skew(-10deg);
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work anymore with current Chrome version 72

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`text-rendering: geometricPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) CSS property. This will force your text to not be anti-aliased, thus making the blurriness less important.

```js
inp.onchange = function(){
   document.querySelector('.child').classList.toggle('geo');
  }
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);body{color:#fff;font-weight:bold;font-size:50px;font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif;}

.geo{
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  }
.parent {

  transform: skew(-10deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  
  width:300px;padding-left:15%;margin-left:-15%;overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  transform: skew(10deg);  
  width:300px;background: rgba(90, 190, 230, 0.9);padding-left: 5%;padding-right: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> <!-- skew(-10deg) -->
    <div class="child geo">Hello</div> <!-- skew(10deg) (skew back) -->
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="inp" checked="true"/> geometricPrecision
```

Comment: Thanks, Better !, But when i zooming by Photshop, I got same result. (Chrome on Mac)  http://i.imgur.com/ksgKKPV.png

Comment: Yes it's not perfect, I added a toggle so you can see that it still improves things.

Comment: Yes, Its better :D