# Text blurring only on firefox with animation

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, antialiasing, font-smoothing

Trying to get a clean text for my view.
This code shows clean text on chrome/IE but not on Firefox which for some reasons shows me a blurry text.

Here's a reproduction of my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/z7egrnod/

Does anyone have a solution to counter this ? I just can't understand how is it possible to have a blurry text.

```
.skewContent {
height: auto;
-o-transform: skewY(-6deg);
-moz-transform: skewY(-6deg);
-ms-transform: skewY(-6deg);
-webkit-transform: skewY(-6deg);
transform: skewY(-6deg);
transform-origin: top left;
overflow: visible;
}

.skewContent#toolbox {
    margin-top: -110px;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.containerSkew .skewFix {
-o-transform: skewY(6deg);
-moz-transform: skewY(6deg);
-ms-transform: skewY(6deg);
-webkit-transform: skewY(6deg);
transform: skewY(6deg);
}
```

Image example on chrome :

[image: ON chrome]

Image example on firefox :

[image: ON Firefox]

Comment: Please fix the link of the `reproduction of your problem`.

Comment: Done, @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: You are doing skew back and forth on the text. Don't apply the skew on text.

Comment: @sabithpocker Then how can I have the text being normal in a div who is skewed ?

Comment: Depends, if you only want a skewed background or so, you can use a pseudo element using `:before` or `:after` and skew it instead.

Comment: Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501435/chrome-text-blurry-when-skew-back-skew-10deg-skew10deg)

Comment: So I have to use the pseudo element `:before` to make the background skewed so I can normally use the div skewContent right ? @sabithpocker

Comment: Yes, [this answer already got one live example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501815/427146)

Comment: I have some difficulty to apply it; when I add ::after on containerSkew nothing is changing for some reason. Do I have to change the css class to put every skew changement into the pseudo element after or is there smthing else ? @sabithpocker

Comment: You can either post a new question or update the questing with your updated problem. Your current issue is not clear without a code snippet.

Comment: Got it in the end, thx !